# How do immutable languages implement set, concat, equals and such efficiently?

Tags: algorithm, optimization, data-structures, compiler-construction, immutability

Certain array operations such as `set`, `equals` and `concat` would be considerably slow (mostly O(n)) if they needed complete structure copy on memory. I'm aware immutable languages such as Clojure use some tricks to avoid big complexity on those operations. What are those tricks?

Comment: Not saying this is a dup but take a look at the answer for  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16270598/what-is-the-data-structure-behind-clojures-sets it has some interesting links.

Answer (score 1):

Because of the guarantees of persistent data structures "structural sharing " is used in Clojure.  This means for example if you're adding to a list/vector with cons/conj the old data structure is shared between both the old and the new.

Behind-the-scenes the data is stored in shallow trees with high branching factors.

Rich Hickey himself discusses the basic structures and their optimization [in this video](http://youtu.be/wASCH_gPnDw?t=30m19s)